# How to find available dates with query

Tags: laravel

Could you help me build a query to find free dates in Laravel Eloquent.

So I have two models, Node and Booking.
Models are related by HasMany relations

```
public function dates()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Booking::class, 'object_id', 'nid');
}
```

The model of booking have the following structure:

```
| bid | object_id  | checkin    | checkout   |
|  1  | 32         | 2017-04-25 | 2017-04-28 |
|  2  | 32         | 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-09 |
|  3  | 44         | 2017-04-21 | 2017-04-24 |
|  4  | 51         | 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-08 |
```

My purpose is to find available Nodes between given dates.

So, if I want search one date between (for example created_at) it's simple:

```
whereBetween(‘created_at’, [$date1, $date2])
```

But how to create a search query between two dates of checkin and checkout?

Comment: `whereRaw( [$date1, $date2]);` you can do like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$query->where('checkin','<=', $date)
      ->where('checkout','>=', $date);
```

You could also add it to a scope: [Laravel query-scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: Ha, you beat me to it! but this is the exact way!